# HP DV6 can't open fan to lubricate (picture inside)

Tags: fan, oil

A couple days ago, My Laptop (HP dv6-6c65se) fan started alternating between no noise (but still working) and high noise (as if the fan is hitting a metal) every few minutes. I tried cleaning the dust but the same noise remained. After doing some research, I found that I might need to oil (or lubricate) the fan.

The issue is that I can't open the place where I can put the oil. Here is a picture of my fan:

First side:

[image]

(I removed the sticker but I can't open under it)

Other side:

[image]

How to solve this issue?

Fan Model: AD505HX-EEB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a sealed, "lubricated for life" fan; You're not intended to open it, and doing so will probably destroy it permanently.

Just get a new compatible cooler from an HP authorized repair depot, or wherever. There are currently [many listed on EBay](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2047675.m570.l1313.TR0.TRC0.H0.XAD505HX-EEB&_nkw=AD505HX-EEB&_sacat=0) for under $20, for example.

Comment: Thank you. I just wanted to make sure if there was any hope for the original fan before buying another fan.

Comment: The time and pain you'll save by just buying a direct replacement is worth it. ;)